# Arch Linux VPN + L2TP: connection established internet works but no access to internal network

Tags: networking, vpn, dns, arch-linux, l2tp

I configured VPN according to [this](https://documentation.meraki.com/MX/Client_VPN/Client_VPN_OS_Configuration#macOS) instruction (I have Linux), everything is fine, the connection is established, the IP address changes from mine to USA, but the resources that are should be available by VPN is still not available.

Setting up the same connection according to the same instructions but only for Windows 10 - everything works and resources are available. On Linux, the traffic to these resources does not go through the VPN server, but I still could not figure out how to fix it, because I am not strong in this. My systems info:

```
$ cat /etc/*release
NAME="Arch Linux"
PRETTY_NAME="Arch Linux"
ID=arch
BUILD_ID=rolling
ANSI_COLOR="38;2;23;147;209"
HOME_URL="https://www.archlinux.org/"
DOCUMENTATION_URL="https://wiki.archlinux.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://bbs.archlinux.org/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.archlinux.org/"
LOGO=archlinux
```

My assumption is that traffic is bypassing the VPN server and goes thru the default gateway.

Here is what nslookup shows

```
$nslookup confluence.internal.mycompany.com
Server:    8.8.8.8
Address:  8.8.8.8#53
```

I  think it makes sense to try [Routing](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Openswan_L2TP/IPsec_VPN_client_setup#Routing), but I am not cool in the network administrating and don't know how to determine the right subset address. For example aaa.internal.mycompany.com, bbb.internal.mycompany.com, ccc.internal.mycompany.com etc. I want to direct traffic to aaa,bbb,ccc thru the VPN, how do that?

Here is also tcpdump information that might help:

```
13:57:39.163855 IP 172.16.203.173.41032 > 8.8.8.8.53: 44676+ A? confluence.internal.mycompnay.com. (50)

00:06:11.353064 IP 172.16.203.173.39547 > 8.8.4.4.53: 13730+ A? confluence.internal.mycompany.com. (50)
00:06:11.484299 IP 172.217.1.46.443 > 172.16.203.173.35770: Flags [P.], seq 1:40, ack 39, win 269, options [nop,nop,TS val 1580986377 ecr 1105408237], length 39
00:06:11.484400 IP 172.16.203.173.35770 > 172.217.1.46.443: Flags [.], ack 40, win 502, options [nop,nop,TS val 1105408387 ecr 1580986377], length 0
00:06:11.525396 IP 8.8.4.4.53 > 172.16.203.173.39547: 13730 NXDomain 0/1/0 (113)
00:06:11.525562 IP 172.16.203.173.39547 > 8.8.4.4.53: 32697+ AAAA? confluence.internal.mycompany.com. (50)
00:06:11.697698 IP 8.8.4.4.53 > 172.16.203.173.39547: 32697 NXDomain 0/1/0 (113)
00:06:11.698212 IP 172.16.203.173.48215 > 8.8.8.8.53: 13821+ A? confluence.internal.mycompany.com. (50)
00:06:11.698276 IP 172.16.203.173.48215 > 8.8.8.8.53: 19952+ AAAA? confluence.internal.mycompany.com. (50)
00:06:11.859694 IP 8.8.8.8.53 > 172.16.203.173.48215: 13821 NXDomain 0/1/0 (113)
00:06:11.872141 IP 8.8.8.8.53 > 172.16.203.173.48215: 19952 NXDomain 0/1/0 (113)
00:06:11.873004 IP 172.16.203.173.49336 > 8.8.8.8.53: 36616+ A? confluence.internal.mycompany.com. (50)
00:06:12.034300 IP 8.8.8.8.53 > 172.16.203.173.49336: 36616 NXDomain 0/1/0 (113)
00:06:12.034472 IP 172.16.203.173.49336 > 8.8.8.8.53: 34317+ AAAA? confluence.internal.mycompany.com. (50)
00:06:12.195798 IP 172.16.203.173.33819 > 8.8.8.8.53: 61396+ A? translate.google.com. (38)
00:06:12.197393 IP 172.16.203.173.49098 > 216.58.192.206.443: Flags [P.], seq 2343637690:2343638004, ack 443265426, win 11148, options [nop,nop,TS val 2103047503 ecr 1587334695], length 314
00:06:12.209082 IP 8.8.8.8.53 > 172.16.203.173.49336: 34317 NXDomain 0/1/0 (113)
00:06:12.209542 IP 172.16.203.173.54539 > 8.8.8.8.53: 62574+ A? confluence.internal.mycompany.com. (50)
00:06:12.209658 IP 172.16.203.173.54539 > 8.8.8.8.53: 56421+ AAAA? confluence.internal.mycompany.com. (50)
00:06:12.334328 IP 172.16.203.173.56738 > 172.217.6.2.443: Flags [P.], seq 1835541891:1835541930, ack 3334813663, win 502, options [nop,nop,TS val 324800469 ecr 1444482233], length 39
00:06:12.334456 IP 172.16.203.173.56978 > 216.58.192.130.443: Flags [P.], seq 712232265:712232304, ack 2284899148, win 502, options [nop,nop,TS val 1560658341 ecr 3970133710], length 39
00:06:12.334525 IP 172.16.203.173.56994 > 172.217.4.37.443: Flags [P.], seq 175676537:175676576, ack 336787689, win 24353, options [nop,nop,TS val 525175697 ecr 3037756038], length 39
00:06:12.334592 IP 172.16.203.173.45234 > 172.217.8.195.443: Flags [P.], seq 840900759:840900798, ack 624615808, win 1323, options [nop,nop,TS val 2439520764 ecr 528658266], length 39
00:06:12.348814 IP 216.58.192.206.443 > 172.16.203.173.49098: Flags [.], ack 314, win 1050, options [nop,nop,TS val 1587377915 ecr 2103047503], length 0
00:06:12.358256 IP 8.8.8.8.53 > 172.16.203.173.33819: 61396 2/0/0 CNAME www3.l.google.com., A 216.58.192.206 (75)
00:06:12.358483 IP 172.16.203.173.39682 > 8.8.8.8.53: 10206+ AAAA? translate.google.com. (38)
00:06:12.370884 IP 8.8.8.8.53 > 172.16.203.173.54539: 56421 NXDomain 0/1/0 (113)
00:06:12.382054 IP 8.8.8.8.53 > 172.16.203.173.54539: 62574 NXDomain 0/1/0 (113)
```

Am I right that it's not correct? Traffic should not follow thru google's DNS, right?

Here is what  `netstat -r` with off vpn:

```
$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlp2s0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlp2s0
```

with vpn on:

```
$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         U     500    0        0 ppp0
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlp2s0
192.0.2.1       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    500    0        0 ppp0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlp2s0
192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    600    0        0 wlp2s0
208.100.17.99   192.168.0.1     255.255.255.255 UGH   600    0        0 wlp2s0
```

I tried [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Openswan_L2TP/IPsec_VPN_client_setup#Routing) but failed: I lost internet connection

Here is my VPN settings in network manager:

[image]
[image]
[image]

How can I troubleshoot it?

Answer (score 1):

> I want to direct traffic to aaa,bbb,ccc thru the VPN, how do that?

I'm assuming that these are local addresses (as you claim in the title), for example `192.168.0.2`. Packets to that address dont go through the tunnel interface because you have a more specific route than the default route pointing to the `wlp2s0` :

```
192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    600    0        0 wlp2s0
```

With static routing, more specific routes always 'win'. To solve this you can do the following:

1. Delete the current route using `ip route delete 192.168.0.1`
2. Add a new route to that prefix (which addresses the aaa,bbb,cc hosts) with the interface (`dev`) pointing to the tunnel interface. For example:
   `ip route add 192.168.0.1/24 via $IP_OF_TUNNELGATEWAY dev ppp0`

Comment: seems that `ip route delete 192.168.0.1` has no effect. I changed the command to `ip route delete 192.168.0.1` and route was deleted. Here is how `route -n` was looking:
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         U     500    0        0 ppp0
192.0.2.1       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    500    0        0 ppp0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlp2s0
208.100.17.99   192.168.0.1     255.255.255.255 UGH   600    0        0 wlp2s0

Comment: I know it's maybe not very tactfully but I completely failed with fixing this issue and cannot explain it well enough to get help from ppl. Would it be possible to make a call I would share the screen and we try to figure out what the issue? Or maybe you could advise another person who doesn't mind make a call. Thanks

Comment: I checked the stackexchange guides and I guess that's acceptable. Drop me an email via the address found in my bio.

Comment: Thanks, sent you an email

Comment: Seems that I overcome this problem. Please, check the answer does it make sense to you?

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I solved my problem. It's a long story. The root cause is the wrong DNS configuration as a result internal(behind the VPN server) addresses couldn't be resolved properly. An assumption why it happened is the following. Every time I connect to VPN the following chain of events happen:

1. -> networkmanager

   -> [strongswan](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Openswan_L2TP/IPsec_VPN_client_setup#Installation) ppp0

   -> dhclient ppp0 (172.16.203.173, 192.0.2.1, dns1=x.y.z.11, dns2=x.y.z.12) -> resolvconf

   ppp0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1400 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN group default qlen 3
   link/ppp
   inet 172.16.203.173 peer 192.0.2.1/32 scope global ppp0
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

   -> dns1=x.y.z.11, dns2=x.y.z.12 to /etc/resolv.conf

DNS addresses were taken from the VPN connection configuration(see screenshot above).

2. A new route `default via ppp0 metric 500` was added to the routeing table. Its priority less than the default enp3s0 priority `0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enp3s0` as result no traffic flow thru the ppp0. **first issue**
3. /etc/resolv.conf which contains dns1 and dns2 is overridden by network manager at some point of time with default googles dns 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4. **second issue**

To fix the second issue I installed [dnsmasq](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/network-manager/NetworkManager.conf.5.en.html) which serves as a proxy and handles dns by itself. I had to uninstall `pacman -R openresolv netctl` which changed `/etc/resolv.conf` and not it contains the only address of dnsmasq:

```
# Generated by NetworkManager
search internal.mycompany.com
nameserver 127.0.0.1
options edns0 trust-ad
```

to say Network manager use dnsmarq, I also added this line into `/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/dns.conf`:

```
[main]
dns=dnsmasq
```

To fix the first issue in the NetworkManager I added a more specific route that has higher priority than the default enp3s0 route:

```
10.Y.X.Z    192.0.2.1       255.255.255.255 UGH   500    0        0 ppp0
```

That's it. all the traffic to internal resource flow thru the VPN, the rest traffic flows as previously.

Also, I denied any overwriting of /etc/resolve.conf

```
chattr +i /etc/resolv.conf ((to protect the file from write))
```

chattr -i /etc/resolv.conf ((to unprotect, default mode)) - to roll back

Hope it will be helpful for somebody.